# How do I shrink an excel file to print in a single page using XLWings?

Tags: excel, xlwings

I have an excel file where it doesn't perfectly fit in a single page when doing "print to pdf".

This is a regular report where the number of rows will vary from report to report, so it'd be good to have it resize in a programmatic way.

Is there a way to "shrink" the excel to fit in a single page when exported as pdf?

I'm using XLWings, but I'm open to other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You dont say how you're doing the print but something like this might help;

This code sample has a few page setup options.

1. Setup print area if needed using specific range or to max rows
2. Use Zoom to set scaling to percentage
3. Use fit to page
4. Set other options like margins

You can print to a print queue like 'Microsoft Print to PDF' or use Xlwings 'to_pdf'.
If the wb is just opened and printed (not saved) none of these settings will be permanent.

The Page setup options are mainly for print using the Print Queue.
You can duplicate the params from VBA recording if makes it easier to determine which settings you need.

```
import xlwings as xw


xlPrintErrorsDisplayed = 0
xlPrintNoComments = -4142
xlPortrait = 1
xlPaperA4 = 9
xlAutomatic = -4105
xlDownThenOver = 1

excelfile = 'foo.xlsx'
with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
    wb = xw.Book(excelfile)
    ws = wb.sheets('Sheet1')

    mr = ws.range('A' + str(wb.sheets[0].cells.last_cell.row)).end('up').row

    ### Setup a Print Area if required
    # ws.page_setup.print_area = '$A$1:$I$60'
    # ws.page_setup.print_area = f'$A$1:$L${mr}'

    ### Set PageSetup object
    ws_ps = ws.api.PageSetup

    ### Set a scaling
    # ws_ps.Zoom = 25

    ### Fit to Page
    ws_ps.FitToPagesWide = 1
    ws_ps.FitToPagesTall = 1

    ### Other page setup options that may be useful, there are others
    ### Constants like 'xlPrintNoComments' are in the Xlwings constants file, 
    ### I've just included the ones used in the example as hardcoded rather than importing for clarity.
    ws_ps.LeftMargin = 0.75
    ws_ps.RightMargin = 0.75
    ws_ps.TopMargin = 1
    ws_ps.BottomMargin = 1
    ws_ps.HeaderMargin = 0.5
    ws_ps.FooterMargin = 0.5
    ws_ps.PrintHeadings = False
    ws_ps.PrintGridlines = False
    ws_ps.PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
    ws_ps.PrintQuality = 600
    ws_ps.CenterHorizontally = True
    ws_ps.CenterVertically = True
    ws_ps.Orientation = xlPortrait
    ws_ps.Draft = False
    ws_ps.PaperSize = xlPaperA4
    ws_ps.FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
    ws_ps.Order = xlDownThenOver
    ws_ps.BlackAndWhite = False
    ws_ps.PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
    ws_ps.OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
    ws_ps.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
    ws_ps.ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
    ws_ps.AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True

    ### Print to Print Queue 'Microsoft Print to PDF'
    ws.api.PrintOut(Copies=1, ActivePrinter='Microsoft Print to PDF')

    ### Use Xlwings print to pdf
    pdf_file = f"pdf1-2_{excelfile.replace('.', '_')}.pdf"
    ws.to_pdf(path=pdf_file)
```